# Computed Column with relationships

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table, MapLocation, which has a column and two relationships with tables that have a field that really need to be displayed as a single concatenated value. I was thinking this was a perfect case for a computed column, but not sure how to go about it.

```
 MapLocation                          MaoNo                         Section   
_____________________                 _____________________         _____________________
 MapNoId                              MapNoId                       SectionId
 SectionId                            MapNumber (int)               Section (int)
 Identifier (nvarchar)
 LocationName (nvarchar)
```

LocationName = "MapNUmber - SectionNumber - Identifier"
ex: 20 - 03 - SW4

How would I write that? I haven't done much with computed columns or concatenating in SQL.

Edit:

I need an actual computed column that is automatically updated, im looking for the formula. Or is this more of a function/trigger? Its possible, I certainly barely know what I'm doing. The idea is that I dont want to have to do two more server calls and concatenate these values client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use something like this to get the value:

```
select cast(n.MapNumber as nvarchar(10)) + ' - '   -- cast the MapNumber 
    + cast(s.SectionId as nvarchar(10)) + ' - '    -- cast the SectionId 
    + l.Identifier  
from MapLocation l
left join MaoNo n
    on l.MapNoId  = n.MapNoId 
left join Section s
    on l.SectionId = s.SectionId
```

Then if you need to perform an `UPDATE`:

```
update l
set l.LocationName =  (cast(n.MapNumber as nvarchar(10)) + ' - '    
                    + cast(s.SectionId as nvarchar(10)) + ' - '   
                    + l.Identifier)
from MapLocation l
left join MaoNo n
    on l.MapNoId  = n.MapNoId 
left join Section s
    on l.SectionId = s.SectionId
```

Edit #1 - you can use a `TRIGGER`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_LocationName
ON MapLocation
AFTER INSERT
AS
Begin
    update MapLocation
    set LocationName =  (cast(n.MapNumber as nvarchar(10)) + ' - '    
                                        + cast(s.SectionId as nvarchar(10)) + ' - '   
                                        + i.Identifier)
    from Inserted i
    left join MaoNo n
        on i.MapNoId  = n.MapNoId 
    left join Section s
        on i.SectionId = s.SectionId
    where MapLocation.MapNoId  = i.MapNoId  -- fields here to make sure you update the correct record
End
```

Comment: And this equation goes in the Computed column formula?

Comment: when you use the first query, you will get the result when you query it. if you can calculate it, do you want/need to store it in another column?  What do you need this data for?

Comment: Alot of things in my other tables refer to a map location, Example 20 - 02 - SW means the southwest part of section 2 in map 20. I had just hoped when I refer to an element by maplocationID that I wouldn't be greeted with more IDs, viewers only cares about the string.

Comment: @Sethery the problem that I see with a `trigger` is if any of the values are not in their tables, then you will not get your final `LocationName` when you expect to. By calculating it when you need it, you will be sure to get the freshest result.  If you are sure the data will be there, then you can use a trigger.

Comment: I will have dozens of grids with hundreds of elements that reference the MapLocation table, all looking for the X - Y - Z. I thought it'd be good just to have a column with that information already calculated. You cant have a MapLocation without the MapNoId or SectionNoid, they are not nullable, and cascade on delete.

Comment: @Sethery I edited with code for a `trigger` please see my edit. This will execute when a record is added to the `MapLocation` table